Regarding google/ login session issue in muti store website
We are experiencing issues with Google Login and Facebook login on our live site, although they are working in my staging server. it was also working a few days ago.  In my debugging, session generation fails when customers come from third-party URLs. Does anyone have any idea what might be causing this?  Please help
During my debugging, I found that the x-Magento-Vary cookie is not being set. We handle redirection from the popup window using JavaScript.
My Header Response::
HTTP/2 200 
server: nginx
date: Thu, 06 Jun 2024 03:33:43 GMT
content-type: text/html; charset=UTF-8
content-length: 65918
x-sucuri-id: 18002
x-xss-protection: 1; mode=block
x-frame-options: SAMEORIGIN
x-content-type-options: nosniff
content-security-policy: upgrade-insecure-requests;
x-magento-tags: store,cms_b,mp_smtp_script,cms_b_top_bar_need_help,cms_b_footer_need_help,cms_b_footer_address_social_media,cms_b_footer_links,cms_b_footer_copyrights,cat_c_14,cat_c_p_14,cat_p_362110,cat_p,cat_p_299721,cat_p_46940,cat_p_399772,cat_p_303783,cat_p_399222,cat_p_349644,cat_p_232426,cat_p_190045,cat_p_397033,cat_p_397028,cat_p_399773,cat_p_41781,cat_p_49908,cat_p_394550,cat_p_302200,cat_p_401088,cat_p_261917,cat_p_392224,cat_p_399859,cat_p_303969,cat_p_397031,cat_p_346071,cat_p_42280,cat_p_399774,cat_p_299845,cat_p_48163,cat_p_396336,cat_p_397008,cat_p_300363,cat_p_44234,cat_p_397025,cat_p_49915,cat_p_299939,cat_p_48232,cat_p_395448,cat_p_336254,cat_p_398795,cat_p_326113,cat_p_392223,cat_p_387514,cat_p_392221,cat_p_396081,cat_p_392171,mobile,cms_b_social_media_icon_mobile,cms_b_whatsapp_icon_mobile,cms_b_411,amasty_label_entity,amasty_label_entity_11,amasty_label_entity_12
x-content-type-options: nosniff
x-xss-protection: 1; mode=block
x-frame-options: CROSS-ORIGIN
access-control-allow-origin: *
access-control-allow-methods: GET, POST, OPTIONS, DELETE, PUT
content-encoding: gzip
vary: X-Request-ID, Accept-Encoding
x-varnish: 19474984 66166
via: 1.1 varnish (Varnish/6.6)
ttl: 60.000
pragma: no-cache
expires: -1
cache-control: no-store, no-cache, must-revalidate, max-age=0
x-cache-status: HIT
accept-ranges: bytes
access-control-allow-origin: *
access-control-allow-methods: GET, POST, OPTIONS, DELETE, PUT
x-frame-options: SAMEORIGIN
strict-transport-security: max-age=31536000; includeSubDomains; preload
referrer-policy: no-referrer-when-downgrade
x-sucuri-cache: MISS
X-Firefox-Spdy: h2

Server Configuration :
Magento 2.4.3
Nginx
Varnish
Redis
Website Url : https://www.andaazfashion.com.my/
